# How to grant permission on logins in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, permissions

I have two databases.

**Databases:**

```
 1. DB1
 2. DB2
```

I have created two new logins.

**Logins:**

```
1. DB1_login
2. DB2_login
```

Next, I created user for each database mapped to the above logins.

```
create user DB1_login1_user1 for login DB1_login;
create user DB2_login2_user2 for login DB2_login;
```

So, DB1_login1_user1  user of DB1 database will be mapped to DB1_login1 login and DB2_login2_user2  user of DB2 database will be mapped to DB2_login2 login.

Granted database role permissions for both users is **db_datareader** and **db_datawriter**.

In **DB2**, I have a table named **dbo.sample_table**.

***My requirement:***

Let us consider that I have logged in as DB1_login1.

In this login, I have granted permissions for DB1_login1_user1 user to DB1 database.

Now from DB1, I have to select a table **dbo.sample_table** at DB2, which was mapped to another login DB2_login2.

Below is the query what am I trying to do is.

```
--CURRENTLY LOGGED IN AS DB1_LOGIN1
USE DB1; 
EXECUTE as login='DB2_login2'
select * from DB2.dbo.sample_table
GO
```

I tried GRANT IMPERSONATE on LOGIN::DB2_login2 to DB1_login1, but it didn't work and also, I'm not aware about granting permissions across logins. I think granting permissions matters and I need help in doing that.

**How can I execute the above query successfully?**

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The users you created exist only in their respective databases, so what you're trying to do is not possible. Even if it were, or you allow acces (create users for login) in both databases and give then permissions and enable cross-database access, it would be too much of a security risk.

I'd suggest using stored procedures to acces data cross database. Stored procedure should be signed with a certificate, and the same certificate created in both databases. I've had it implemented on various occasions and it works flawlessly.

There is a great sample of this by Erland Sommarskog [here](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#certcrossdb).

Answer (score 0):

I did granting permissions on login.

From administrator login **"Sa"**, I executed the below query.

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::DB2_login to DB1_login;
```

And then from DB1_login, executed the below query for accessing DB across logins.

```
USE MASTER;
EXECUTE as login='DB2_login';
SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.sample_table;
REVERT;
GO
```

Finally for my situation, I have solved the problem.